# Could not find class 'maps.c.i', referenced from method maps.e.al.a

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-2.3-gingerbread

I bumped into an error that is probably due to some mistake I'm doing on my manifest or project java build path (including excluding libraries).

that's the error (plus warnings before):

```
05-15 17:20:25.899: W/dalvikvm(21668): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 47
05-15 17:20:25.909: W/dalvikvm(21668): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 91: Landroid/app/Activity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
05-15 17:20:26.359: I/Google Maps Android API(21668): Google Play services client version: 4323000
05-15 17:20:26.369: I/Google Maps Android API(21668): Google Play services package version: 4325010
05-15 17:20:26.389: W/dalvikvm(21668): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/aj/r; (671)
05-15 17:20:26.399: W/dalvikvm(21668): Link of class 'Lmaps/aj/r;' failed
05-15 17:20:26.399: W/dalvikvm(21668): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ay/an; (6384)
05-15 17:20:26.399: W/dalvikvm(21668): Link of class 'Lmaps/ay/an;' failed
05-15 17:20:26.399: W/dalvikvm(21668): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/c/i; (6615)
05-15 17:20:26.399: W/dalvikvm(21668): Link of class 'Lmaps/c/i;' failed

**05-15 17:20:26.399: E/dalvikvm(21668): Could not find class 'maps.c.i', referenced from method maps.e.al.a**

05-15 17:20:26.399: W/dalvikvm(21668): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 6820 (Lmaps/c/i;) in Lmaps/e/al;
```

My manifest is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prova_fragment"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
         android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.prova_fragment.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="APIKey"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

project build target is Google Api lvl 19

and under java build path I'm using libraries:

- android private libraries
- google apis
- android dependencies

Comment: after some modification to my project the error message has changed into:

**Could not find class 'lyz', referenced from method mbi.a**

Comment: I wrote the same code into more lines and I isolated the problem to:

`FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();`

this is the function giving me this error...